# How to create tkinter dialog on top of windows and always on visible workspace?

Tags: python, linux, tkinter

I'm building an attention-span-focus-reminder thingy. It plays a ting sound and opens a dialog asking if the user is on task. Responding "yes" will increase the time until the next prompt and "no" will shorten it.

It is important that the dialog records a response in a timely manner and the current issue is that it is not always seen.

I have the above working but the dialog needs to stay above other windows and it should stay on the visible workspace. Otherwise it will be forgotten and no answer will be recorded.

Using python and tkinter. I have successfully got a tkMessageBox.askyesno to open. I have been unsuccessful in using any tkinter specific solutions like `root.attributes("-topmost", True)`

I have been able to (in another linux terminal) use the commands `wmctrl -r "On task" -b add,above` and `wmctrl -r "On task" -b add,above`. These do exactly as I want. Using a python shell I've been able to use `os.system('wmctrl -r "On task" -b add,above')`

```py
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()

INCREASE_MODIFIER = 1.01 # Increase by 1%
DECREASE_MODIFIER = 0.95 # Decrease by 5%

while True:
    ## sleep for sleep_time
    print('Sleeping for {}'.format(datetime.timedelta(seconds=sleep_time)))
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
    ## post question "are you on task"
    playsound('ting.mp3')
    answer = askyesno(title='On task?', message='Are you focused on the right thing?')
    os.system('wmctrl -r "On task" -b add,above')
    os.system('wmctrl -r "On task" -b add,sticky')
    root.update()
    if answer:
        sleep_time = sleep_time * INCREASE_MODIFIER
    else:
        sleep_time = sleep_time * DECREASE_MODIFIER
```

The askyesno function blocks until a user responds. This means that the lines for os.system are not ran *while* the dialog is open. But only after it has a response and disappeared.

I need it to display the dialog *then* make the os.system calls *then* it can wait for user response.

Comment: This definitely qualifies as an "ugly hack", but you could try doing the `wmctrl` calls in a separate thread - start the thread just before opening the dialog, and have it sleep for perhaps a second to give the dialog time to open.

Comment: Yep that's pretty much what I've done for now.

Thankfully `wmctrl` doesn't throw a fit when it can't find a window or if it has already been applied etc.